# Method-chaining without permanently mutating the object

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.x, method-chaining

I am learning how to write a python class and method chaining at the moment. Basically, I want a python (2.7) class that keeps my data and has (chain-able) methods that allow me to filter the data without mutating my original data. I have done some Googling and it seems like my answer might have something to do with `return self`, but I am not sure how to implement it such that the methods will not mutate my original data.

Let's say I have a data stored in an excel file called `file` as follows:

```
+--------+-----+-------+
| Person | Sex | Score |
+--------+-----+-------+
| A      | M   |    10 |
| B      | F   |     9 |
| C      | M   |     8 |
| D      | F   |     7 |
+--------+-----+-------+
```

I would like to write a class called `MyData` such that I can do some basic data calling and filtering.

This is what I got so far

```
class MyData:
    def __init__ (self, file):
        import pandas as pd
        self.data = pd.read_excel (file)
        self.Person = self.data['Person']
        self.Sex = self.data['Sex']
        self.Score = self.data['Score']

    def male_only(self):
        self.data = self.data[self.Sex=="M"]
        self.Person = self.Person[self.Sex=="M"]
        self.Score = self.Score[self.Sex=="M"]
        self.Sex = self.Sex[self.Sex=="M"]
        return self

    def female_only(self):
        self.data = self.data[self.Sex=="F"]
        self.Person = self.Person[self.Sex=="F"]
        self.Score = self.Score[self.Sex=="F"]
        self.Sex = self.Sex[self.Sex=="F"]
        return self
```

This seems to work, but sadly my original data is permanently mutated with this code. For example:

```
Data = MyData(file)
Data.data
>>> Data.data
  Person Sex  Score
0      A   M     10
1      B   F      9
2      C   M      8
3      D   F      7

Data.male_only().data
>>> Data.male_only().data
  Person Sex  Score
0      A   M     10
2      C   M      8

Data.data
>>> Data.data
  Person Sex  Score
0      A   M     10
2      C   M      8
```

I would like a class that returns the same answers for `Data.male_only().Person` and `Data.Person.male_only()` or for `Data.male_only().data` and `Data.data.male_only()` without permanently mutating `Data.data` or `Data.Person`.

Comment: If you don't want to mutate the object that you're calling these methods on, then obviously you need to return a *new object*, rather than `self`.  Your current `__init__()` isn't really ideal for this, because it only allows you to create a new `MyData` from a file, rather than from an existing dataframe.

Comment: @jasonharper I am fairy new to this, but my current understanding is that `return self` is essential for method chaining... A code example that returns the same answers for `Data.male_only().Person` and `Data.Person.male_only()` without permanently changing `Data.Person` would be appreciate. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Demi-Lune.

I changed OP's code so that `male_only()` and `female_only()` methods always return copy of its belonging object. And I changed `__init__()` method because I think you don't want to call `pd.read_csv()` method every time creating that new object. So `male_only()` and `female_only()` method always return new object, it will no effect on other objects.

```
import pandas as pd

# Added for creating file on memory.
import io
csv = '''Person,Sex,Score
p1,M,1
p2,M,2
p3,M,3
p4,F,4
p5,F,5
p6,F,6'''
file = io.StringIO(csv)

class MyData:
    def __init__ (self, file=None, data=None):
        import pandas as pd
        if file:
            self.data = pd.read_csv(file)
        else:
            self.data = data
        self.Person = self.data['Person']
        self.Sex = self.data['Sex']
        self.Score = self.data['Score']

    def copy_d(self):
        return MyData(data=self.data.copy())

    def male_only(self):
        d = self.copy_d()
        d.data = self.data[self.Sex=="M"]
        d.Person = self.Person[self.Sex=="M"]
        d.Score = self.Score[self.Sex=="M"]
        d.Sex = self.Sex[self.Sex=="M"]
        return d

    def female_only(self):
        d = self.copy_d()
        d.data = self.data[self.Sex=="F"]
        d.Person = self.Person[self.Sex=="F"]
        d.Score = self.Score[self.Sex=="F"]
        d.Sex = self.Sex[self.Sex=="F"]
        return d

d = MyData(file)
print(d.female_only().data)
#   Person Sex  Score
# 3     p4   F      4
# 4     p5   F      5
# 5     p6   F      6

print(d.male_only().data)
#   Person Sex  Score
# 0     p1   M      1
# 1     p2   M      2
# 2     p3   M      3

print(d.data)
#   Person Sex  Score
# 0     p1   M      1
# 1     p2   M      2
# 2     p3   M      3
# 3     p4   F      4
# 4     p5   F      5
# 5     p6   F      6
```

But if your are just using `pandas.DataFrame`, another approach is just using bare `pandas.DataFrame`. First thing is that, in most case, `pandas.DataFrame` object already has properties name which equals to columns name. So in fact, you don't need to define properties like `Person`, `Sex`, `Score` because it already exists in DataFrame object.

ie:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.eye(3,3), columns=['Person', 'Sex', 'Score'])

# `df` already has these properteis.
df.Person
df.Sex
df.Score
# In [986]: df.Person
# Out[986]: 
# 0    1.0
# 1    0.0
# 2    0.0
# Name: Person, dtype: float64

# In [987]: df.Sex
# Out[987]: 
# 0    0.0
# 1    1.0
# 2    0.0
# Name: Sex, dtype: float64

# In [988]: df.Score
# Out[988]: 
# 0    0.0
# 1    0.0
# 2    1.0
# Name: Score, dtype: float64
```

So, your `male_only()` and `female_only()` methods are written like following.

```
import pandas as pd

# Added for creating file on memory.
import io
csv = '''Person,Sex,Score
p1,M,1
p2,M,2
p3,M,3
p4,F,4
p5,F,5
p6,F,6'''
file = io.StringIO(csv)

def male_only(df):
    return df[df.Sex=='M']

def female_only(df):
    return df[df.Sex=='F']

df = pd.read_csv(file)
male_only(df)
# In [1034]: male_only(df)
# Out[1037]: 
#   Person Sex  Score
# 0     p1   M      1
# 1     p2   M      2
# 2     p3   M      3

female_only(df)
# In [1038]: female_only(df)
# Out[1041]: 
#   Person Sex  Score
# 3     p4   F      4
# 4     p5   F      5
# 5     p6   F      6
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: thank you very much. Your answer is very helpful and I think this is what I am looking for. Just to clarify, it is not about using `pandas.DataFrame` specifically. This is simply an exercise about a python class with methods that allow users to manipulate returned objects without permanently modifying them. I think the core magic is the `copy_d` method, which allows objects to be manipulated without changing the original data. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly modify self.data in the 1st line, when you write `self.data = ...`. You could return a new instance of Data:

```
    def male_only(self):
        newdata = MyData()
        newdata.data = self.data[self.Sex=="M"]
        newdata.Person = self.Person[self.Sex=="M"]
        newdata.Score = self.Score[self.Sex=="M"]
        newdata.Sex = self.Sex[self.Sex=="M"]
        return newdata
```

Following your comments, here's a suggestion of a filter solution: there'd functions to activate some flags/filters, then you'd have to write functions to get the attributes:

```
# self.filters should be initialized to [] in __init__
def male_only(self):
    self.filters.append('male_only')
def person(self):
    if "male_only" in self.filters:
        return self.Person[self.Sex=="M"]
    else: 
        return self.Person
```

To see if this can go somewhere, you should really complete your test-case(s) to help you fix your ideas (it's always good practice to write the test-case first, then the classes).

Comment: Thank you for an answer. However, I don't think this is what I am looking for. For example, this solution would work for `Data.male_only().Person`, but it would fail for `Data.Person.male_only()`...

Comment: Then another possibility would be to manage your object with some kind of "viewing/filtering" capabilities. You should enrich your question with more examples or testcases of what you want to do. I'll edit my answer with an idea of a "filter" solution.

Comment: It is not quite what I am looking for, but certainly is a cool trick. The `person` method is quite useful actually. Many thanks for the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I want to elaborate on @Demi-Lune's answer a bit. I don't think there is a way you can get around creating a `MyData` instance, modifying that, and returning it from your chain methods. The whole reason that this sort of thing works in the first place is that all of your chain methods belong to the same class, and they return an instance of that class.

For example, `str.swapcase`, `str.zfill` and `str.replace` are all a part of `str`, and they all return `str`s.

```
>>> string = "Hello World"
>>> string.swapcase().zfill(16).replace("L", "T")
'00000hETTO wORTD'
>>> string
'Hello World'
>>>
```

What you're trying to do (`Data.Person.male_only()`) breaks this pattern, since it is now implied that the method `male_only` is not part of the `MyData` class, and is instead a method belonging to the `Person` object. What is `self.Person` or `self.data["Person"]`? I'm not super familiar with Pandas. Is it a string? A list of strings? In any case, whatever it is, what you're trying to achieve would basically involve adding a new method named `male_only` to the class of that type.